# Use Flush(True) and FlushFileBuffers both?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, filestream, flush

I want to write to a file and flush to disk immediately.

Other questions on SO pointed out that Flush(True) isn't reliable on .NET 4.0. I am indeed using .NET 4.0 and can't upgrade any time soon.

Is FlushFileBuffers reliable? or is it known to have a bug too?

Is there an option that I can use or should I use both and hope for the best?

Comment: `Other questions on SO` A link to those questions may get you more answers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the "bug" you are talking about is [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20111219010536/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634385/filestream-flush-flushtodisk-true-call-does-not-flush-the-buffers-to-disk):

> .NET Framework 4.0 introduced the new **FileStream.Flush(bool flushToDisk) overload**.
>   If flushToDisk is set to true, it should commit the changes to disk.
>
> However, **in many cases (if internal buffer pointer is 0) the changes are not committed to disk, and the Flush(true) call does absolutely nothing.**
>
> If applications rely on FileStream.Flush(true) working as described, it could lead to data corruption issues.

but according to [Is there an official fix (aka KB) for the FileStream.Flush bug introduced in .Net 4](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb5c77f1-bb72-459f-bb96-e5be50f89477/is-there-an-official-fix-aka-kb-for-the-filestreamflush-bug-introduced-in-net-4-?forum=netfxbcl) it has been fixed with 4.0.3:

> ...As far as I can tell it is fixed in .NET Framework Update 4.0.3 even though it's not mentioned in the KB.